# How to define a method which return attributes from other class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, methods, attributes

In my program I have the following question. How can I define a method in the class 'Mouse' 'Keyboard' and 'Screen' so that they return the room and the computer they belong to + the associated attribute of the class (so for the keyboard class this would be: 'The computer {} is located in the room {} and has the language {} ') Can someone tell me how I can define such a method for these 3 classes without changing the program itself? The method should be defined for each class seperated. The exact task is "Extend the output of maus, screen and tastatur so that the user knows which computer in which room they belong".

I've tried to define the following method:

```
def as_text(self):
        return "{} an {} in {}".format(self.__name, self.__computer, self.__computer.__room)
```

In my three classes I have build in a reference to computer. My Class Computer has a reference to room, so I've tried to call it with `self.__computer.__room` but that doesn't work and I'm not sure how to call this attribute.

Here is my code:

```
class Room:
    __name = "unknown"

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    
class Device:
    __name = "Device"

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def as_text(self):
        return "%s" % (self.__name)

class Computer(Device):
    __ip = "unknown"
    def __init__(self, name, ip, room):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.__ip = ip
        self.__room = room

    def as_text(self):
        return "%s with ip=%s" % (super().as_text(), self.__ip)
        

class Laptop(Computer):
    def __init__(self, name, room, ip, with_case = True):
         super().__init__(name, room, ip)
         self.__with_case = with_case

    def as_text(self):
        if (self.__with_case):
            return "%s with case" % super().as_text()
        else:
            return super().as_text() 
   
class Screen(Device):
    __width = "1920"
    __height = "1080"
    def __init__(self, name, width, height, computer):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height
        self.__computer = computer

    def as_text(self):
        return "{} an {}".format(self.__name, self.__computer)


class Tastatur(Device):
    __language = 'English'
    def __init__(self, name, language, computer):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.__language = language
        self.__computer = computer
    

class Maus(Device):
    __type = 'Gaming Mouse'
    def __init__(self, name, type, computer):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.__type = type
        self.__computer = computer
```

Comment: stop using double-underscore name-mangling like this. Also, stop creating a class variable only to *immediately* shadow it with an instance variable in `__init__`

Comment: That is a requirement of my teacher, it has to stay that way

Comment: Be aware, you are learning "Java in Python". In any case, what have you tried? It is unclear what you mean by the requirement "Can someone tell me how I can define such a method for these 3 classes without changing the program itself? " What do you mean without changing the program itself? Defining a method *is changing the program itself*. But in any case, your requirements/restrictions are totally clear to me.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm sorry, but it's a program my teacher gave me. I'm just supposed to make a few changes like what I mentioned above. Do you know how i could do this

Comment: Again, *have you tried anything at all*? I'm sorry, but this isn't a tutoring service for your class. We aren't just going to do your homework for you. What is it that is giving you trouble, *exactly*?

Comment: So I tried tried to definde a method, where i return those attributes - it looked something like that ` def as_text(self):
        return "{} an {}".format(self.__name, self.__computer)`  In my programm, I have a reference to computer (look at the constructor) and the computer class has a reference to the class room. But how can I call this room attribute in my method?

Comment: Don't post that in a comment, edit your question and add the details there.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this website.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not particularly clear, here what I got.
This is my method for the Screen Class:

```py
def as_text(self):
            return "{} an {} in {}".format(super().as_text(), self.__computer.as_text(), self.__computer.display_room())
```

```
 super().as_text()
```

This calls the method `as_text` from the parent class Device.

```
 self.__computer.as_text()
```

This calls the `as_text()` method from an instance of the Computer class, which is an attribute of your class Screen.

```
self.__computer.display_room()
```

This calls the method `display_room()` from the Computer class, I created it and returns the Room's name.

```py
def display_room(self):
        return self.__room.get_name()
```

Now you should be able to write methods for Tastur and Maus yourself.